# Websocket HandshakeRequest throwing ClasscastException

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spring-security, websocket

I have a Grails 2.5 application for which I am adding websocket support. The websocket has been added using this blog as guide : http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2014/12/07/using-websockets-in-grails/
The integration works when creating a grails application from scratch, but when I try to integrate within my application it throws this stacktrace

```
| Error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be
cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; | Error     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHandshakeRequest.<init>(WsHandshakeRequest.java:73)
| Error     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(UpgradeUtil.java:149)
| Error     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:77)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.processFilterChain(UrlMappingsFilter.java:440)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:241)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
| Error     at
com.application.CustomAuthFilter.super$3$doFilter(CustomAuthFilter.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method) | Error     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) | Error
    at
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
| Error     at
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207) |
Error   at
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1121)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
| Error     at
com.application.CustomAuthFilter.doFilter(CustomAuthFilter.groovy:368)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:169)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:93)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:157)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:103)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:83)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:102)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
| Error     at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:230)
| Error     at
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
| Error     at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
| Error     at
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
| Error     at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
| Error     at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
| Error     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
| Error     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
null
```

Any help as to how to diagnose the problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: If I put the url of the controller that makes the websocket connection outside of spring-security, I don't get this error anymore and connection is being made successfuly.

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using? Are you sure you are using consistent versions of Tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat version 7.0.54. Sample application is working, the only difference being my application has spring-security-plugin for grails.

Comment: What version of spring-security-plugin are you using?

Comment: compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.4"

Comment: Honestly I'm a bit stumped it appears something is overriding the HttpServletRequest getParameterMap() which contains a value that is of type ArrayList instead of type Object[]. Looking at Spring Security 3.0.7.RELEASE (the version that the plugin uses) there is nothing that overrides the request with the wrong type. Can you provide a complete sample to reproduce?

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing the issue outside of the codebase. I looked at the src for tomcat and on line 73, the original parametermap was an array and then its being changed to a list in the HashMap. Here are the lines:

Comment: Map<String,String[]> originalParameters = request.getParameterMap();
        Map<String,List<String>> newParameters =
                new HashMap<String, List<String>>(originalParameters.size());
        for (Entry<String,String[]> entry : originalParameters.entrySet()) {
            newParameters.put(entry.getKey(),
                    Collections.unmodifiableList(
                            Arrays.asList(entry.getValue())));
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of @Rob Winch. You pointed me in the right direction when you said that something is rewriting the HttpServletRequest object. It turns out some custom groovy code was adding parameters to the request object by using this groovy notation : [str]. This actually is java.util.ArrayList in Groovy and not a String [] (array). This was what caused the hand shake request to fail. Thanks again Rob.